# What are mouse LS cells?

Tags: cell-culture, mouse

I have seen the term "mouse LS cell" used in several papers now, but I haven't found an explanation for the origin of these cells (for example, [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Doug_Kilburn/publication/17407921_The_effect_of_dissolved_oxygen_partial_pressure_on_the_growth_and_metabolism_of_mouse_LS_cells/links/0fcfd506f59a6bc46c000000.pdf)).

What are mouse LS cells? What is their origin (besides coming from mouse!)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not an easy question, but I got some references about it.
Mouse LS cells are Fibroblasts growing in suspension culture, the paper in reference 1 has this paragraph in its Materials and Methods section:

[image]

This cell line seems to be in culture since the 1940s, as the reference to Sanford, Earle and Likely, 1948 suggests. Digging up this reference (number 2 below) tells a bit more about the isolation:

> The cells of this study were from Earle's strain
>   L (6), which originated from normal, subcutaneous,
>   connective tissue of an adult C311 strain
>   mouse.

Reference 6 in the Sanford et al. paper is:

> EARLE, W. R.: Production of malignancy in vitro.
>   IV. The mouse fibroblast cultures and changes
>   seen in the living cells. J. Nat. Cancer Inst, 4:
>   165-212 (1943).

which gives no further details. It is a methodic paper which analyzes the conditions necessary for cell culture - interesting on a historical point of view, since the techniques where developed at that time. The full PDF is linked in reference 3.

About the name I need to speculate a bit, but since the original cells where named "Strain L", and LS cells where derived from there to grow in suspension, it might translate into Strain L Suspension cells.

References:

1. [The Uptake of Amino Acids by Mouse Cells (Strain LS) During Growth
   In Batch Culture and Chemostat Culture: The Influence Of Cell Growth
   Rate](http://www1.zippyshare.com/v/2qt5re0c/file.html)
2. [The Growth in Vitro of Single Isolated Tissue Cells](http://www94.zippyshare.com/v/6NV4Pait/file.html)
3. [Production of Malignancy in Vitro.](http://www.cuneyttas.com/EBSS-sol-J-of-National-Cancer-Institute-1943-Vol4-Iss2-pp165-212.pdf)